# Jmeter execution from CMD

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run JMeter script from CMD trying to fetch report in CSV file. I am getting error level 1=1 error:

[image: error on running jmeter from cmd]

How to get that resolved?

Comment: Share your code and error in text format, that will help expert to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is wrong:

- You must add -t before the JMX test plan
- Surround your path with "" and give the full path including "C:\"

JMeter can help you by typing:

> jmeter -h

and

> jmeter -?

Command line for you is:

> jmeter.bat -n -t test-file [-p property-file] [-l results-file] [-j log-file] -e -o [Path to output folder]

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options